# Consolidate a Duplicate Value Based on Criteria from other Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have many duplicate lines of data and want to consolidate them without always summing the last cell.

**Here is my example set of data:**

[image: Example Data]

I want to find where the place, name and date are all the same and return the total for the day as a single number (Where the place, name and date match, the data in the Total for the day column will always be duplicated - in this example that means that everything that matches Venice, `John` and `2/07/2018` will always be 1)

Where there is then a mismatch of name, then this gets treated as a second value that is added to the first i.e. (`Venice`, `John`, `2/07/2018`)  +  (`Venice`, `Barry`, `2/07/2018`) `=2`
However this is ONLY when the `NAME` does not match.

**In the end I want the result to appear like this:**

[image: Result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I need the end user of this to not have to do anything. No data removed, no pivot tables
APOLOGIES ALL: Cell K2 (Italy 30/7/2018) should read: 1.5 and Cell I3 (London 9/7/2018) should equal 1 :S

Comment: unpivot or powerquery

Comment: Remove duplicates, its on the data tab.  Then use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

=sumifs(D:D;A:A;"Venice";C:C;"02/07/2018") should do the trick. You can obviously change the sum if criteria into (absolute) references of your table. For instance, change "Venice" into $F$2 if that's where your summary table field is located

Comment: This will only return a sum of all in Venice on that Date. So in this example, it will return a 6. But this needs to return a 2 to reflect that there were 2 names and each had a 1 as a total for the day.

Comment: I do not want to question your reasons, but why would you chose to duplicate lines that bear the exact same information. It makes finding a solution very difficult. If you wouldn't do that, and just just every person once, the solution would be rather easy to obtain, no?